# bootstrap 3 max & min resolutions for col-*

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am quite impressed with the latest version of bootstrap. And I have started to work on it. Now I can understand that the grid system works on 4 column class size variants, with the following definition:

```
col-xs-* ---> mobile

col-sm-* ---> tablet

col-md-* ---> laptops

col-lg-* ---> large monitors
```

However, I need to know, what is the minimum and maximum resolutions for which these classes gets applied on so that I can design the layout better.

**I am asking this because, I could see col-md class applied at 800px. I generated this resolution using Firefox's responsive view simulator.**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [the documentation for the grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid):

> /* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
>   /* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */
>
> /* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
>   @media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { ... }
>
> /* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
>   @media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { ... }
>
> /* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
>   @media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }

It also provides the container widths:

- .col-xs-*: none (auto)
- .col-sm-*: 750px
- .col-md-*: 970px
- .col-lg-*: 1170px

Comment: Did you try that out, I could see col-md picking up at 800px itself :(

Comment: What do you mean "picking up"? These don't control what is visible or not. This is for sizing your columns.

Comment: I meant, col-md is applied at 800px width

Comment: If you only set the object to use the col-md-* class, it assumes that 970 is the minimum width of the browser.

Answer (score 2):

col-xs-* = less than 768px

col-sm-* = 768px and up

col-md-* = 992px and up

col-lg-* = 1200px and up

Comment: Did you try that out, I could see col-md picking up at 800px itself :(

Answer (score 0):

For detail about Bootstrap 3 you can follow this link [Bootstrap 3 Grid options](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)

- Extra small devices Phones (<768px)  (col-xs)
- Small devices Tablets  (≥768px) (col-sm)
- Medium devices Desktops (≥992px)     (col-md)
- Large devices Desktops (≥1200px) (col-lg)